# Can't center align a cleared div after using javascript to switch from float:left to clear:both (WHY?)

Tags: html, css, layout, stylesheet

I'm using javascript to change stylesheets based on resolution, and I wanted to know why divs that are previously floated left can not be centered after changing the div to center:both.

Here are the after.css, before.css, before2.css code:

From: after.css (this is the stylesheet used when I want to switch float:left to centered AND clear:both)

```
.foobar {
    clear:both;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

From: before.css (switching to after.css will clear but NOT center)

```
.foobar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin: 12px;
}
```

and here is before2.css (switching to after.css will clear AND center)

```
.foobar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's really hard to say what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: add float:clear to each div that needs to be dynamically switched to clear:float.